# Why every time I need to check for variable values in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react and get `profile is null` error sometimes when page is refreshed . For this I am putting all the code `inside if` like

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCurrentProfile();
  if(user && profile){
  setFormData({
    name:user && user[0].name,
    phone: loading || !profile[0].phone ? '' : profile[0].phone,
    company: loading || !profile[0].company ? '' : profile[0].company,
    website:loading || !profile[0].website ? '' : profile[0].website,
  });
}

}, [loading, getCurrentProfile]);
```

Here you can see if I don't put `if(user && profile)` condition then I got `profile is null` error.

**I am writing a bad code or this is only the way to write it ?**

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, are you asking for other ways to check for `null`? What you have is a perfectly valid null check, if you don't think the variable should be null at this point then you may have a problem further up the code (e.g. in `getCurrentProfile`)

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const user = getCurrentProfile();
  if(user){
  setFormData({
    name:user && user[0].name,
    phone: loading || !profile[0].phone ? '' : profile[0].phone,
    company: loading || !profile[0].company ? '' : profile[0].company,
    website:loading || !profile[0].website ? '' : profile[0].website,
  });
}
}, [loading, getCurrentProfile]);

useEffect(() => {
  getCurrentProfile();
  if(user && profile){
  setFormData({
    name:user && user[0].name,
    phone: loading || !profile[0].phone ? '' : profile[0].phone,
    company: loading || !profile[0].company ? '' : profile[0].company,
    website:loading || !profile[0].website ? '' : profile[0].website,
  });
}
}, [user, profile, loading, getCurrentProfile]);
```

there is a closure inside useEffect,it will read once your user and profile,therefore you will get null,include in your dependencie array [user,profile,loading, getCurrentProfile]) or return your user data in in getCurrentProfile function